# EF6 ignore (NotMapped) all enum type properties

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, enums, model-binding

I have a pretty big EF model, and I'm trying to avoid going through each class and fishing for properties that are of type `enum` and setting `[NotMapped]` attribute on top of them. What I was hopping to is was to write smth like this

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder){
  modelBuilder.Properties<enum>().Configure(p=>p.Ignore());
  ....
```

or

```
modelBuilder.Properties().Where(p=>p.GetType().IsEnum).Configure(p=>p.Ignore());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can ignore properties on the type configuration level, so you need start from `modelBuilder.Types()` and not from `modelBuilder.Properties()`:

```
modelBuilder.Types().Configure(typeConfiguration =>
{
    foreach (var property in typeConfiguration.ClrType
        .GetProperties().Where(p => p.PropertyType.IsEnum))
    {
        typeConfiguration.Ignore(property);
    }
});
```